# Authentication failed

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, hudson

i got this error after setting a slave node, somebody please help~
i can ssh on the slave node without problem, it only happens on jenkins.

```
[11/20/14 21:01:30] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.105.5.34:22.
[11/20/14 21:01:30] [SSH] Authentication failed.
hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1178)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[11/20/14 21:01:30] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[11/20/14 21:01:30] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

jenkins version is the latest 1.59, ssh plugin also is the latest

Comment: i follow the steps provided here http://docs.omnirom.org/Adding_a_Slave_node_to_Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try to ssh to the host using this command:

ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa remoteuser@server

where the id_rsa (or dsa) is your key. Test it well because that's probably where your problem is. On the server look at the auth.log. You should be able to see errors in case of:

- home permissions/ownership are not OK
- .ssh permissions/ownership are not OK
- keys permissions/ownership are not OK

Key based authentication is very strict towards permissions of the keys, home and the .ssh folder. Especially if strict mode is turned on in the sshd_config of the SSH server. You should have something like that set:

chmod go-w ~/ 
chmod 700 ~/.ssh 
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys